# How to inherit from MonkeyDevice?

Tags: android, python, inheritance, monkeyrunner

I would like to extend the MonkeyDevice class of the monkeyrunner API.
My derived class looks like this.

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice, MonkeyRunner

class TestDevice(MonkeyDevice):
    def __init__(self, serial=None):
        MonkeyDevice.__init__(self)
        self = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(deviceId=serial) 
        self.serial = serial
```

When I call `test_dev = TestDevice(serial)` from another module I get the following error:

```
    test_dev = TestDevice(serial)
TypeError: _new_impl(): 1st arg can't be coerced to com.android.monkeyrunner.core.IMonkeyDevice
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code language is this in?

Comment: I have not use monkeyrunner, but from what I see... why are you reassigning `self`?, I mean you are passing the original self, to the constructor of `MonkeyDevice` which if fine and the right way to do it, then you are just dropping that `self`!, is this the right way to do it with monkeyrunner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you cannot directly initialize a `MonkeyDevice` instance without a call to a factory function `waitForConnection`. So instead you need to assign `self` in your `__new__()` function so that `MonkeyDevice` recognizes the instance as inheriting from `IMonkeyDevice` before you call it's `__init__`

Example:

```
class TestDevice(MonkeyDevice):
    def __new__(self, serial=None):
        return MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(deviceId=serial) 
    def __init__(self):
        MonkeyDevice.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to extend a `MonkeyDevice` instance returned by factory call `waitForConnection`.

When you try to substitute `self` inside the construtor you get an error (?).
I suspect you are running Jython, as CPython would not complain here, instead a local variable `self` is created and its value lost.

Anyway to achieve what you want you should create a class with custom `__new__` rather than `__init__`, get your `MonkeyDevice` instance from the factory and inject your stuff into the instance or it's class/bases/etc.

Alternatively you could wrap `MonkeyDevice` into another class and pass monkey-ish calls and member access though `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`.

Comment: good point, at the second glance the problem is more obvious, rewriting the answer.