# Python class to inherit MonkeyDevice

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

I followed the solution as given here and added a method to extend functionality to my Device class.
[How to inherit from MonkeyDevice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433433/how-to-inherit-from-monkeydevice)

I get an error object has no attribute 'test'.  Looks like my Class instance is of type MonkeyDevice. What am I doing wrong?

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage

class Device(MonkeyDevice):

    def __new__(self):
        return MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10) 
    def __init__(self):
        MonkeyDevice.__init__(self)
    def test():
        print "this is test"

device = Device()
device.test(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of things wrong. Unfortunately I don't use `monkeyrunner` so I can't help you with the details related to the library itself.

What your code does is something like the following:

```
>>> class MonkeyRunner(object): pass
... 
>>> class Device(MonkeyRunner):
...     def __new__(self):
...             return MonkeyRunner()
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(Device, self).__init__()
...     def test():
...             print "This is test"
... 
>>> device = Device()
>>> device.test(self)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MonkeyRunner' object has no attribute 'test'
>>> device
<__main__.MonkeyRunner object at 0xb743fb0c>
>>> isinstance(device, Device)
False
```

Note how `device` is **not** a `Device` instance. The reason is the your [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method is not returning a `Device` instance, but a `MonkeyRunner` instance. The answer that you linked in your question states:

> Anyway to achieve what you want you should create a class with custom
>   `__new__` rather than `__init__`, get your `MonkeyDevice` instance
>   from the factory **and inject your stuff into the instance or it's
>   class/bases/etc.**

Which means you should have done something like:

```
>>> class Device(MonkeyRunner):
...     def __new__(self):
...             inst = MonkeyRunner()
...             inst.test = Device.test
...             return inst
...     @staticmethod
...     def test():
...             print "I'm test"
... 
>>> device = Device()
>>> device.test()
I'm test
```

However this isn't useful at all, since the `Device` could simply be a function:

```
>>> def Device():
...     def test():
...             print "I'm test"
...     inst = MonkeyRunner()
...     inst.test = test
...     return inst
... 
>>> device = Device()
>>> device.test()
I'm test
```

AFAIK you cannot subclass `MonkeyRunner` and create the instance from its `waitForConnection` method, at least if `waitForConnection` is a `staticmethod`.

What I'd do is to use delegation:

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._device, attr)
    def test(self):
        print "I'm test"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your answers especially the last one.

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` is the method used to actually instantiate the object.  Because you've overridden it and explicitly returned whatever MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection returns, device is not actually an instance of class Device.

It's rare to need to override `__new__`.

*edited*
OK, I see from the linked answer that this is a case where you need to do that.  Bakuriu's answers show some ways to work with the need to use the special constructor to instantiate the object, as do the docs for `__new__`: [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

As a minor note, by convention the first argument to `__new__` is cls rather than self, because it's actually the class object itself rather than an instance.